# undefined, nodejs, json to program, variable scope problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, undefined

I am trying to write a program that will take an object stored in an array in my json file and to use the object in my program, but every time I try to put the json object in an array within my program, and run my main file it gives me an undefined value. This is obviously a variable scope problem as the variables for what I want to access are located within the callback function and not the parent function "getGenesis" outside of it. There are two files here to focus on and that is the json file and the Blockchain file.
following debugging:

```
main@goldengates.club [~/public_html/Cypher-Network]# node index.js
undefined
listening at localhost:3000
```

relevant Blockchain file:

```
const Block = require('./block');
const Transaction = require('../wallet/transaction');
const Wallet = require('../wallet');
const { cryptoHash } = require('../util');
const { REWARD_INPUT, MINING_REWARD, GENESIS_DATA } = require('../config');
const fs = require('fs');
const jsonRoute = '/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/CDSM/CDSM.json';

class Blockchain {
  constructor() {
    this.chain = [Blockchain.getGenesis()];
}

//further into the file.....

static getGenesis() {
     fs.readFile(jsonRoute, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;

    const jsonChain = JSON.parse(data);
    const genesis = jsonChain.blocks[0].GENESIS_DATA;
    //console.log(genesis);
    
    /*console.log(jsonChain.blocks[0].GENESIS_DATA.lastHash); //specify element of where the object is and the field that you want to read*/
    
    /*jsonChain.blocks.push({
        GENESIS_DATA
    });

    console.log(jsonChain);
    
        fs.writeFile('CDSM/CDSM.json', JSON.stringify(jsonChain), 'utf-8', function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Done!');*/
        return genesis;
    });
//returning it here also yields an undefined since the variables are out of the scope 
}
//assuming that the class bracket is closed after skipping unnecessary code
}
```

following json file:

```
{"blocks":[{"GENESIS_DATA":{"timestamp":1,"lastHash":"v01d","hash":"?M=(((Position-1)=>ter)=>sen)=>non?","difficulty":20,"nonce":0,"data":[]}}]}
```

how do I re-write this so that I can access the genesis variable?

Comment: I think the return data is already in json format

Comment: Why are you parsing the data again , if it already a json ?

Comment: it will return with some sort of encoded line of string, to take it out from json u must parse and to bring it back in u need to stringify. Or do I have it all wrong, please explain if I have the wrong idea.

Comment: I think I know what I may have done wrong, a silly mistake

Comment: ok so I have fixed part of the issue, but because of inheritance, the return whether I put it out of the callback function or just outside of it in getGenesis function will always return undefined for when I need to add the object into an array for my constructor, I will update my getGenesus function code right now

Comment: I have edited my question to fit the appropriate context after fixing the small mistake

Comment: An easy solution for such cases: Step 1: Make sure your json file is trusted. Step 2: use eval();

Comment: I did some reading and it seems like this could pose security issues. But I am not sure if this fixes my scope problem as my callback is where I can access the contents of the json, and that is a more narrow scope